# How do you call a component in another component in react?

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs

I'm trying to have make a form where if you push a button you get another form from another component.
So far no luck

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
//var CompetenceActions = require('../actions/CompetenceActions.js');
var Alert = require('react-bootstrap/Alert');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;
var KeybehaviourComponent = require('./KeybehaviourComponent.js');

var CompetenceComponent = React.createClass({
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Competence Name: <input type='text' id='competencename'  onChange={this._onChangeName} autoFocus={true}/><br/>
                        Competence Description: <input type='textarea'  id='competencedescription'  onChange={this._onChangeDescription}/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.addKeybehaviour}>Add Keybehaviour</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <button onClick={this.submitForm}>submit</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    /* jshint ignore:end */

    getInitialState:function(){
        return ({
            competenceName: '' ,
            competenceDescription: ''
        });
    },

    _onChangeName: function(/*object*/ event) {
       this.setState({
         competenceName: event.target.value
       });
    },

    _onChangeDescription: function(/*object*/ event) {
        this.setState({
            competenceDescription: event.target.value
        });
    },
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    addKeybehaviour:function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <KeybehaviourComponent/>
            </div>
        );
    },
    /* jshint ignore:end */

    submitForm:function(){
         console.log(this.state.competenceName);
         console.log(this.state.competenceDescription);
         //CompetenceActions.createCompetence(competenceName, comptenceDescription);
         //this.setState({competenceNameValue: this.props.competenceName, competenceDescriptionValue: event.target.comptenceDescription});
    }
});

module.exports = CompetenceComponent;
```

that is my first component where i create a form, render it and call another form when i push a button'

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
//var CompetenceActions = require('../actions/CompetenceActions.js');
var Alert = require('react-bootstrap/Alert');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

var KeybehaviourComponent = React.createClass({
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    Keybehaviour Name: <input type='text'  defaultValue='name' id='keybehaviourname'  onChange={this._onChangeName} autoFocus={true}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Keybehaviour Description: <input type='text' defaultValue='description' id='keybehaviourdescription'  onChange={this._onChangeDescription}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    /* jshint ignore:end */

    getInitialState:function(){
        return ({
            keybehaviourName: '' ,
            keybehaviourDescription: ''
        });
    },

    _onChangeName: function(/*object*/ event) {
        this.setState({
            keybehaviourName: event.target.value
        });
    },

    _onChangeDescription: function(/*object*/ event) {
        this.setState({
            keybehaviourDescription: event.target.value
        });
    }
});

module.exports = KeybehaviourComponent;
```

this is the component called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just return a react component in an onClick. I'll try to get you started on the solution. You should do something like this in the `addKeybehaviour` function:

```
var newAmount = this.state.currentAmount + 1;
this.setState({currentAmount: newAmount});
```

Now in your render function of `CompetenceComponent` try doing something like:

```js
var keyboardComponents = [];
for (i = 0; i <= this.state.currentAmount; i++) {
    keyboardComponents.push(<KeybehaviourComponent />)
}
```

Now just put {keyboardComponents} somewhere in your return function. Hope this gets you started.